# Restoring files on ntfs

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery, gparted

So I was using gparted to extend my NTFS partition, but the linux desktop went to sleep and caused gparted to close before it was done.

I ran chkdsk /f /r on the drive and it seemed to repair it; however, my video files are not playing properly. (You open one file and bits and pieces of other files play.) Is there anything else I can do to fix/restore the data or should I assume it to be lost?

Recent out put of chkdsk /f /r:

```
1231427583 KB total disk space.
 789785036 KB in 39544 files.
     16760 KB in 4111 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    235951 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 441389836 KB available on disk.

4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
307856895 total allocation units on disk.
110347459 allocation units available on disk.
```

Comment: Have you tried running gparted again and letting it finish? Or is the repaired partition bigger?

Comment: The repaired partition is bigger.